# TestNG/RestAssured : Is there any way we can reuse @Test methods in different classes?

Tags: java, automation, testng, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am a newbie to automation. I am using Rest-Assured. And I want to validate response for every request like for example checking if response is null or status code, status line, content-type etc .
Is there any way I can reuse those @Test methods written for validation??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reuse @Test to validate every response. `ResponseSpecification` can be used to combine common checkings. For example:

```
ResponseSpecification resSpec = new ResponseSpecBuilder()
        .expectStatusCode(200)
        .expectContentType("application/json")
        .build();

Response res = given().get("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo=bar");
res.then().spec(resSpec);
```